# Lightswitch Add/Edit screens are not localized

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm trying to get my Silverlight Client localized, but I'm stuck with the Add/Edit dialog boxes being localized as well. Everything works correctly except these dialogs. Here are some screenshots:

Here's the localization settings:

[image]

It's working fine on the grid:

[image]

But not on the Add/Edit dialogs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You need to localize the server tier.**

To do so :

- In Solution Explorer, expand the Data Sources node, and then open the
  entity.
- In the Entity Designer, choose a field to localize.
- In the Properties window, choose the Display Name property, and then
  enter $(PropertyName).
- Then add a resources file for default language (which always is
  English) , and then name it Service.resx.
- Add values to it regarding to your properties names (e.g. Name:
  PropertyName, Value: Name)
- Add another resource file with desired language (e.g. Service.ar-AR).
- Add values to your localized resource file.

Take a look at:
Walkthrough: Localizing a LightSwitch Application (jump to: To localize the server tier)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Xx130603(v=VS.120,d=hv.2).aspx

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Actually "You need to localize the server tier." is my answer, the link is just an addition. Hence he knew how to localize :)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It might be better to quote the relevant section of the walkthrough (leaving the link as a reference though), so people won't mistake this as a link-only answer (which is not considered a proper answer on Stack Overflow).